# Why is return false not keeping my form from submitting?

Tags: javascript, validation, form-submit

### http://jsfiddle.net/1z9Lr5rv/1/

I am creating a contact form for my website.  I thought it was working fine, but it always submits the form, wether or not there's an error, where `return false` should keep the form from submitting.

I'm sorry if this is really obvious and dumb, but I'm very new to this sort of thing . . .

Comment: because that's not how you stop events from being passed to the default browser handling. You stop that with `evt.preventDefault()`. returning false only signals that if bubbling can be cancelled, it should be.

Comment: Note that the value of a form control is a string, so where *fname* is a form control, `fname.value == null` will *always* return false.

Comment: @RobG.  That's not true.  I'm using it in my code now and it works perfectly.

Comment: It absolutely **is** true. ;-) The condition in your code "works" because you have `fname.value == null || fname.value == ""`. The first condition is always false, so the outcome of the test rests on the result of the second. You can safely remove it (see my answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form works fine if you take it out of JS Fiddle (you should post the code here anyway). Here it is (with the redundant parts removed):

```
<div class="body">If you have any questions about me, my teaching or curriculum, etc., please don't hesitate to contact me here. Please fill out all the fields in this form..
  <br>
  <br>
  <form name="contact-me" class="contact-me" onsubmit="return warnsub(this)"
     method="POST"
    action="https://secure.mailjol.net/allforms/u/3dcdda44.php" autocomplete="off">
    First Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname">
    Email Address: <input type="text" name="email">
    Message: <textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
  </form>
</div>


<script>

function warnsub(form) {
    var error = [];
    var fname = form.fname;
    var lname = form.lname;
    var email = form.email;
    var message = form.message;
    var atpos = email.value.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = email.value.lastIndexOf(".");

    if (fname.value == "") {
        error.push(fname);
    }
    if (lname.value == "") {
        error.push(lname);
    }
    if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= email.length) {
        error.push(email);
    }
    if (message.value == "") {
        error.push(message);
    }

    if (error.length) {
        for (i = 0; i < error.length; i++) {

            // You want to clear this class if the user has another
            // attempt and gets it right
            error[i].className = 'error';
        }
        error[0].focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  The JSFIDDLE was set to run JS onLoad.

Answer (score 2):

You need to handle the event object that is automatically passed into the submit handler and call `preventDefault()`.

Example:

```
var myForm = document.forms["contact-me"];

myForm.onsubmit = function(e)
{
    if(!warnsub())
    {
    e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

As @Pointy has commented: IE9 does not automatically pass the event object to the `onsubmit` delegate. Discussion of how to shiv this is outside the scope of this question.

But just a side note - its good to try and avoid function calls in inline html (e.g. `<form onsubmit=//your function() />` calls. Your Google-Fu can teach you why.

Comment: should be `.onsubmit` not just `.submit` - also old versions of IE don't pass the event object as a parameter

Comment: @Pointy - right you are (jQuery making me lazy) updated.